# how to sum amount based on 2 columns that are both dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, group-by, sum

i have a tbl_remit where i need to get the last remittance.

I'm developing as system wherein I need to get the potential collection of each Employer using the Employer's last remittance x 12. Ideally, Employers should remit once every month. But there are cases where an Employer remits again for the same month for the additional employee that is newly hired. The Mysql Statement that I used was this.

```
SELECT Employer, MAX(AP_From) as AP_From, 
                MAX(AP_To) as AP_To, 
                MAX(Amount) as Last_Remittance, 
                (MAX(Amount) *12) AS LastRemit_x12
FROM view_remit
GROUP BY PEN
```

Result

```
|RemitNo.|  Employer  |  ap_from  |   ap_to   | amount |
|   1    |      1     |2016-01-01 |2016-01-31 |  2000  |
|   2    |      1     |2016-02-01 |2016-02-28 |  2000  |
|   3    |      1     |2016-03-01 |2016-03-31 |  2000  |
|   4    |      1     |2016-03-01 |2016-03-31 |   400  |
```

By doing that statement, i ended up getting the wrong potential collection.

```
What I've got:
400 - Last_Remittance
4800 - LastRemit_x12 (potential collection)

What I need to get:
2400 - Last_Remittance
28800 - LastRemit_x12 (potential collection)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I don't have a team in this project. this may be a novice question to some but to me it's really a complex puzzle. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter the data for the last time period.  So, think `where` rather than `group by`.  Then, you want to aggregate by employer.

Here is one method:

```
SELECT Employer, MAX(AP_From) as AP_From, MAX(AP_To) as AP_To,
       SUM(Amount) as Last_Remittance,
       (SUM(Amount) * 12) AS LastRemit_x12
FROM view_remit vr
WHERE vr.ap_from = (SELECT MAX(vr2.ap_from)
                    FROM view_remit vr2
                    WHERE vr2.Employer = vr.Employer
                   )
GROUP BY Employer;
```

EDIT:

For performance, you want an index on `view_remit(Employer, ap_from)`.  Of course, that assumes that `view_remit` is really a table . . . which may be unlikely.

If you want to improve performance, you'll need to understand the view.

Comment: When i used your code, it's been Loading since forever :( do you think because i have 200,000 remittance transactionss /rows in my view? Or do i have to tweak something in php.ini :( i'm using google chrome and xampp v3.2.1

Comment: Unfortunately, view_remit is not a table. I'll try exporting it and make it a table then try the code again. :)

Comment: @Clorae . . . When you do that, adding the index will help performance.